# Problems using mdsymbol (\mid and \surd already defined errors)

Tags: fonts, errors, warnings

I'm trying to use Minion Pro and Myriad Pro in some of my documents and to use the accompanying mdsymbol package for math fonts. I'm getting the following errors when compiling a basic document:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\mid' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2041 ...thSymbol{mid}{\mathrel}{delimiters}{"B6}

! LaTeX Error: Command `\surd' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.2109 ...thSymbol{surd}{\mathop}{delimiters}{"D3}
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{mdsymbol}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Assuming the duplication is within `mdsymbol`, you could `\let\surd\relax` and `\let\mid\relax` before loading `mdsymbol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that neither `Myriad.sty` (so you really have `MyriadPro.sty`?) nor `mdsymbol.sty` are well-written IMNSHO. Given that they are designed for use with Minion, you'd expect them to at least be compatible with it. But both files define macros with names identical to those used by `MirionPro.sty`. However, unlike the latter, which is sensitive to the possibility that the macros may already have been defined, neither of the problematic `.sty`s takes any notice at all of this possibility.

The result is that it works if you are careful about the order of loading, but the maintainers of `MyriadPro.sty` and `mdsymbol.sty` ought to include suitable checks or pick up predictable clashes and issue meaningful error messages. The first solution would be far preferable.

This works for me:

```
\documentclass[british,final]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{Myriad}% I have Myriad.sty and not MyriadPro.sty
\usepackage{mdsymbol}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note it is better to pass the language and document status as class options unless you've special reason not to, and that it is better to specify the language variant than rely on `english` defaulting to the variant you want.

Also, this MWE could have been reduced: `microtype`, `babel` and `sourcecodepro` are all irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it doesn't find MinionPro.sty and MyriadPro.sty or you have other definitions somehow in conflict. Do you have installed the right font in the right directory? (usually /usr/local/teTeX/share/texmf-local)

Try to read the README:
http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/minionpro/README

If this is not the problem it may depends by your TeX specific installation i think but from your log is cler that you loaded something which already defines that commands...
Try evetually to run \meaning\mid and \surd to get from where is coming...
(it should say for \mid \mathchar"37B6)

Comment: I installed both MinionPro and MyriadPro using the instructions from here: https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro and they are both installed in my local texmf tree (on the Mac it's $HOME/Library/texmf/ and related subtrees)

Comment: Running the get meaning commands I get the following: `macro:->\delimiter "3353353 macro:->\protect \surd`

Comment: That is certainly not the 'usual directory' on any system I'm aware of. It is definitely not the directory if you have a default installation. On a Unix-ish system, you'd use `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`, though to be sure you can use `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)` in the path you give. `teTeX` suggests a very old installation. `share`  seems odd. Is this the effect of some Linux distro's repackaging? If so, the directory you have is likely to be a very parochial choice indeed.

Comment: There's no reason at all to think it can't find the `.sty` files. @GregoryGelfond.

Comment: There's also zero reason to think the fonts aren't installed correctly.